# Radius of convergence of the series-power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Can anyone help me to check whether my solution is correct because we are not provided with the solutions,but I want to ensure what I did is correct. Thanks for your help!

(a)$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 5^n (2n)! x^n/(n!)^2$
    My answer is Radius of convergence is $1/20$

(b) 
    $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^nx^{2n+1}$
    My answer is Radius of convergence is 1/2

Thanks anyone who can help me check it!

Comment: You should show your work, rather than just state the results you obtained.

Comment: Both problems yield  to the Ratio Test. The first radius of convergence is correct, and the second is not.

Comment: @AndréNicolas ohya, the second one should be sqrt(2) /2, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty{2n\choose n}~t^n~=~\frac1{\sqrt{1-4t}}$ . In this case, $t=5x$.